# Can't detect hash type even if I have the password?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking

I can't found the hash type used in a database hosted in a VM.

My hash is `c39e02416d974229752c28d7fcefe6e1`, and my password is "azerty123456". I noticed that the user table has a column called `password_type`. It hold the value "default". Also the username is "aya".

I tried to use hash-identifier to detect the hash. This is the result:

```
 HASH: c39e02416d974229752c28d7fcefe6e1        

Possible Hashs:
[+]  MD5
[+]  Domain Cached Credentials - MD4(MD4(($pass)).(strtolower($username)))

Least Possible Hashs:
[+]  RAdmin v2.x
[+]  NTLM
[+]  MD4
[+]  MD2
[+]  MD5(HMAC)
[+]  MD4(HMAC)
[+]  MD2(HMAC)
[+]  MD5(HMAC(Wordpress))
[+]  Haval-128
[+]  Haval-128(HMAC)
[+]  RipeMD-128
[+]  RipeMD-128(HMAC)
[+]  SNEFRU-128
[+]  SNEFRU-128(HMAC)
[+]  Tiger-128
[+]  Tiger-128(HMAC)
[+]  md5($pass.$salt)
[+]  md5($salt.$pass)
[+]  md5($salt.$pass.$salt)
[+]  md5($salt.$pass.$username)
[+]  md5($salt.md5($pass))
[+]  md5($salt.md5($pass))
[+]  md5($salt.md5($pass.$salt))
[+]  md5($salt.md5($pass.$salt))
[+]  md5($salt.md5($salt.$pass))
[+]  md5($salt.md5(md5($pass).$salt))
[+]  md5($username.0.$pass)
[+]  md5($username.LF.$pass)
[+]  md5($username.md5($pass).$salt)
[+]  md5(md5($pass))
[+]  md5(md5($pass).$salt)
[+]  md5(md5($pass).md5($salt))
[+]  md5(md5($salt).$pass)
[+]  md5(md5($salt).md5($pass))
[+]  md5(md5($username.$pass).$salt)
[+]  md5(md5(md5($pass)))
[+]  md5(md5(md5(md5($pass))))
[+]  md5(md5(md5(md5(md5($pass)))))
[+]  md5(sha1($pass))
[+]  md5(sha1(md5($pass)))
[+]  md5(sha1(md5(sha1($pass))))
[+]  md5(strtoupper(md5($pass)))
```

I tried to generate the hash using my password "azerty123456" and salted it with either my username or the value of the `password_type` column, but I don't get the same hash.

Comment: Do you have any other hints to work with, like what application generated these password hashes?

Comment: its a php script

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but I assume there's no way to look at the source code?

Comment: thank u for asking not a dump question !
no at now i try to figure out a way to login with the admin password ...

Comment: Can you generate new passwords? Try a „a“ and „b“ and try to set the same password multiple times. Also try different users with same password. Also look for a seed/pepper Key in the config files or tables. Or just post the name/vendor of the app.

Comment: I will create a new user using the same password to see if I got the same hash. if not I will rename the username to "aya" (and the old account "aya" i will change it to another name ) to see the changes ... thank u eckes i will be back if i got a result .

Comment: Hashes are not designed to tell you "This hash was generated via MD5". Given that you know the output is 128 bit, it's likely to be MD5. What you are trying to figure out now is "Which input was used to generate this hash?". This question is more commonly known as "Cracking a hash" and without access to the source code, guessing the format will not be easy either.

Comment: it confirmed that even I change the username I get the same password, I used a new account and another username , with the same password and i get the same hash

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot of information to work with here, as your hash-identifier tool has already pointed out.

Things we know:

1. `c39e02416d974229752c28d7fcefe6e1` is 16 bytes (or 128 bits). [There are no modern hash functions with an output this short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Unkeyed_cryptographic_hash_functions), so that suggests that it's likely MD5. (unless its something like SHA1 truncated to 128 bits, but who would do that??)
2. Your hash-identifier tool could not figure it out, which means they're doing some obfuscation; adding the username as a salt in a weird way, or using an application-wide salt, or using a MAC with an application-wide secret key, or iterating the hash some number of times, or some combination.

Unfortunately, unless you can find some more information in the database that gives you some hints (or if you can get access to the source code of the php application), then you are faced with a hard reverse-engineering problem :(

Comment: "id,username,password,email,mobile,register_ip,register_time,register_user_agent,last_login_ip,last_login_user_agent,lang,vip_plan,vip_end_time,ref_id,is_admin,wallet,wallet_usd,password_security,password_type,action_id"
these are the columns in "user" table. 
there are some dynamic values and some constant . I try to combine my password with some constant value but I need a program that helps me to generate every combination .

Comment: What's in the `password_security` column?

Comment: I knew that u will ask ! for a normal user its an empty field but for admin (its hold a hash and the password field hold half of another a hash ) exemple 
admin password : 224beb70bd7d3f29efbbeeb
password_security : 663a40bd51b9afdaeed7a8d5c163f342

Comment: I return to my Tables list to see if there are any hints...
I found 3 tables related to user authentication. login , login_security , token
Table: login
[6 columns]

 `key`, `time`, id, ip, login_type, user_id FROM login WHERE (user_id = my_id)
[*] 3fdab63fce14174f99b8be67b6b0958b, 1552665788, 29517, XX.XX.XX.XX, system, my_id

Comment: 3fdab63fce14174f99b8be67b6b0958b is in same type as password wolumn in table user (according to hash-identifier comparaison )